# How to print some specific atributes of derived class using overload <<

Tags: c++, sharepoint, overloading, derived-class

I have a base Class named Animals and 2 derived class Dog and Cat

```
class Animal{

protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string color;
public:
    std::string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    std::string getColor() {
        return color;
    }
...
```

```
class Cat : public Animal {
private :
    int lives;
public :
    int getLives() {
        return lives;
    }
...
```

```
class Dog : public Animal {
private :
    std::string gender;

public:
    std::string getGender(){
        return gender;
    }
...
```

and i have e vec of shared_ptr

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> animals
```

I've added some cats and dogs in the vector and i am trying to print all the characteristics of each animal from vector ,using operator >>(this is a homework,we have to use this ) and i did this

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& v)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        os << v[i]->getName();
        os << "-";
        os << v[i]->getColor();
        if (i != v.size() - 1)
            os << ", ";
            os<<"\n";
    }

    return os;
}
```

but in this way i can print only the name and color or the animals(these atributes are in the base class)
My question is : 
How can i print all the attributes ,for cats lives and for dogs gender???

Comment: and how to do this ??i mean,what to put in this template .It's the first time i use template and overload >> :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Animal {

protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string color;
public:

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os){
        os << "Name:" << name <<" Color:"<< color;
    }

    void setName(string n) { name = n; }
    void setColor(string c) { color = c; }
    std::string getName() {
        return name;
    }

    std::string getColor() {
        return color;
    }
};
class Cat : public Animal {
private:
    int lives;
public:
    void setLives(int n) { lives = n; }
    void print(std::ostream& os) {
        Animal::print(os);
        os <<" Lives:"<<lives;
    }
    int getLives() {
        return lives;
    }
};
class Dog : public Animal {
private:
    std::string gender;  
public:
    void setGender(string g) { gender = g; }
    void print(std::ostream& os) {
        Animal::print(os);
        os << " Gender:" << gender;
    }
    std::string getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
};  
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        v[i]->print(os);
        os << "\n";
    }   
    return os;
}    
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Dog> d1 = make_shared<Dog>();
    d1->setName("Dog1"); d1->setColor("White"); d1->setGender("Male");
    shared_ptr<Cat> c1 = make_shared<Cat>();
    c1->setName("Cat1"); c1->setColor("Brown"); c1->setLives(1);
    vector<shared_ptr<Animal>> vec;
    vec.push_back(d1);
    vec.push_back(c1); 
    cout << vec;   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt know who is this get : Animal::get(os);

Comment: Animal is base class and it's attributes are common to the derived classes. Typos it should read Animal::print(os). Corrected.

Comment: I have another question : if i have to find some specific element in vector and remove ,why this is not working ? ```auto it=std::find_if(animals.begin(),animals.end(),
                         [&](std::shared_ptr<Animal> const& a){
                             if(a->getColor()=="Brown"){
                                 return a;
                             }
                         });

    animals.erase(it);```

Comment: It should work. For removing node, you may read  erase-remove idiom and use std::remove_if

Comment: Your code in comment is incorrect, replace it like so: `auto it = std::find_if(animals.begin(), animals.end(),[&](std::shared_ptr<Animal> const& a) { return a->getColor() == "Brown"; });animals.erase(it);`